# How do I realize an arrow representing "line numbers" in LyX?

Tags: lyx, diagrams

I want to draw an arrow, who shall represent line numbers like in the following screenshot.

[image: line numbers]

I struggeled with xymatrix, but this doesn't seem to be the right approach. Any ideas?

Comment: This kind of drawing would be relatively easy to draw in tikz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is pretty straight forward using [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz); here's something to get you started

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw the arrow
  \draw[->](0,0)--(10,0);
  % draw the tick marks
  \foreach \x/\nodename/\mytext in {1/a/$2(N-1)\omega$,5/b/$2N\omega$,7/c/$2\omega_0$,9/d/$2(N+1)\omega$}
  \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[anchor=north](\nodename){\mytext};
  % draw the braces
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10}]($(a.north)+(0,.25)$)--($(b.north)+(0,.25)$)node[anchor=south,pos=.5,outer sep=.5cm]{$|2\omega|$};
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10}]($(b.north)+(0,.25)$)--($(c.north)+(0,.25)$)node[anchor=south,pos=.5,outer sep=.5cm]{$|2\omega_0-2N\omega|$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Notes**

I hope that most of the code is pretty self-explanatory; one of the pieces that isn't immediately obvious (to someone who hasn't seen a lot of `tikz` code) is the line

```
\foreach \x/\nodename/\mytext in {1/a/$2(N-1)\omega$,5/b/$2N\omega$,7/c/$2\omega_0$,9/d/$2(N+1)\omega$}
```

The way that I read this is to think that `\x`, `\nodename`, and `\mytext` are all loop variables, and they will take the values specified in the following curly braces (separated by the delimeter `/`).

So

- `\x` will take the values `1,5,7,9`
- `\nodename` will take the values `a,b,c,d`
- `\mytext` will take the values `$2(N-1)\omega$,...,$2(N+1)\omega$`

I've used

- `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}` for the braces; the `amplitude` key controls the amplitude of the brace
- `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to tweak the vertical positioning of the braces, for example `($(a.north)+(0,.25)$)` means to use the `node` named `a` north's position PLUS `(0,.25)`

The `tikz` package provides a huge number of tools, so there are probably multiple ways to do this- my code is just one such way :)