# Drawing a vertical line with sections

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I've looked to another example but struggle to adapt it to my needs. Tikz is new to me.

```
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.style={shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt}]
  \draw (0,0)  node [below] {0} -- (1,0) node [below] {1};
  % draw the tick marks
  \coordinate (p) at (0,2pt);
  \foreach \myprop/\mytext [count=\n] in {0.06/$p_1$,0.06/$p_2$,0.06/$p_3$,0.06/$p_4$,0.06/$p_5$,0.15/$p_6$,0.13/$p_7$,0.14/$p_8$,0.15/$p_9$,0.13/$p_10$}
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2}] (p)  edge [draw] +(0,-4pt) -- ++(\myprop,0) coordinate (p) node [midway, above=2pt, anchor=south] {\mytext} ;
  \path (1,2pt) edge [draw]  ++(0,-4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Latex squeeze all the values together instead of spreading them over the 0 to 1 axis.

Comment: Please search the site to see if something has been done already before you ask a new question. :) Anyway, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80041/4778

Comment: By the way, why did you ask for a "vertical line"? The line in your image is horizontal.

Comment: Horizontal is right, I struggle with the adjective. Thanks for the link to other question, I searched but didn't have the key words.

Comment: Well, you didn't share any detail as to how you want to do this. Use the code from that question to draw whatever you can do. But for example: how many ticks you want? Is the distance between the ticks regular? Or is it not? Do you want to simply replicate the image?

Comment: In my case there is 10 ticks, from 1 to 10. The distances between is not equal.

Comment: Can you complete the code so we can copy-paste-compile it please? That's much more useful than a fragment.

Comment: The `another example` is, presumably, now my answer - or part of my answer - rather than the example you started with. Surely it would be only polite to acknowledge this fact?

Comment: `0.06` + ... `0.13` or whatever should add up to 10.

Comment: It is spreading them over the entire width of the 'axis' but you have made the axis only 10% the width it had in my original code below. So obviously things will overlap and look very squashed. You have forced far too much stuff into an area with width of only 1cm.

Comment: Note that the use of other people's code without attribution is rather rude. In some cases, it will also be illegal and/or violate site policies. But the fact that common courtesy requires it is a more compelling and, in this case, more plausible consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to modify things:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.style={shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt}]
  \draw (0,0)  node [below] {0} -- (10,0) node [below] {1};
  % draw the tick marks
  \coordinate (p) at (0,2pt);
  \foreach \myprop/\mytext [count=\n] in {1/$p_1$,2/$p_2$,.5/$p_3$,1/$p_4$,5/\dots,.5/$p_n$}
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2}] (p)  edge [draw] +(0,-4pt) -- ++(\myprop,0) coordinate (p) node [midway, above=2pt, anchor=south] {\mytext} ;
  \path (10,2pt) edge [draw]  ++(0,-4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified loop]

Comment: Thank  you for both examples. Its a whole new world Tikz and its quite amazing stuff. THANKS

Comment: I have tried to adapt the example codes and get a really ugly picture. How can this be changed, I'm sure its a simple matter for someone that knows Tikz.

Comment: Change `{1/$p_1$,2/$p_2$,.5/$p_3$,1/$p_4$,5/\dots,.5/$p_n$}` to alter the number, placement and labels. The numbers before the `/`s should add up to 10. Each `.../...` creates one segment. To change the amplitude you can alter `amplitude=2`. For bigger ticks, you can increase `2pt` and `-4pt`. The negative number should be `-2` times the positive number. That's about it really. It is hard to know what you want to change just from the information in your comment.

Comment: Sorry the total value of the axis should equal to 1, I've changed this now.

Comment: That means that the total width of your diagram will be `1` i.e. 1cm. Do you really want to create a miniature diagram? The 10 is just intended as a reasonable default width. If you need something only 1cm wide, you need to rethink your diagram completely because you clearly don't have space for that many labels etc. in such a small space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example. Following your comment after the question, I have put 10 segments (11 ticks).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw segment and ticks
    \draw[-](0,0)--(10,0) foreach~in{0,...,10}{(~,-2pt)--(~,2pt)};
    % draw braces and labels
    \foreach[count=\j]\i in{0,...,9}
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace](\i cm + 1pt,3pt) -- node[above,font=\scriptsize]{$p_{\j}$} (\j cm - 1pt,3pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]